# Git Client in Jenkins 1.6 on windows is not cloning remote git (Bitbucket) repository, timed-out

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a bitbucket repository and i want to fetch it in a job of jenkins 1.6, Git Client and Git plug-ins are latest. Config of the job for git is without name, refspec and additional behaviour. repository URL is https://bitbucket.org/charlieapp/proejct-name.git. I have specify the credential with username and password in the drop down.   When i run the job i get following error in console log:

> Started by user anonymous
>   Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Charlie Portal build and deploy
>   git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git.exe config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/charlieapp/proejct-name.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/charlieapp/proejct-name.git
>   git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git.exe config --local credential.username user # timeout=10
>   git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Windows\TEMP\git466607659423377716.credentials\" # timeout=10
>   Setting http proxy: 172.18.65.22:80
>   git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/charlieapp/proejct-name.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>   git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Comment: Same error if i set time out as 60 min in Advance Clone behaviour of git

Comment: proxy is set in under Manage Jenkins->Plugin->Advance tab. not sure if it is set for both http and https

Comment: as a workaround i manually cloned the repository using git command window in jenkins job workspace and now doing shallow clone